# I see all my html in echo

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, pdo

I send data as array to php and check it with echo. OK it works. I see my username. But when i add $pdo i see all my html (that i do not want to see). What is wrong with this?

This is my javascript

```
var appAdmin=angular.module('appLogin',[]);
appAdmin.service('loginService',
    function($http) {
        this.submitLogin=function(username,password){
            return $http({method:'POST',
                url: "php/checkLogin.php",
                data: {
                    username: username,
                    pass: password
                },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }); //use $http() here.
        }
    });
appAdmin.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,loginService){
    $scope.user={};
    $scope.submitLogin=function(){
        loginService.submitLogin($scope.user.username,$scope.user.password)
            .then(function(data,status,config,headers){
                debugger;
                console.log('Response from server: '+data.data);
            },
                function(data,status,config,headers){
                    console.log('Some error occurred!'); //called in case of error
                }
            )
    }
});
```

This is my PHP

```
<?php
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    @$username = $request->username;
    @$password = $request->password;
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=subscribers', 'tuviak',    'tuvik1002') ;
    echo htmlspecialchars($username, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); //this will go back under "data" of angular call.
?>
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styleAdmin.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="appLogin" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <form name="frmLogin" novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="username" ng-hide="true">
        <input type="text" name="password" ng-hide="true">
        <div id="loginBox">
            <div class="lineBox">
                <span class="label">Username</span>
                <input type="text"   name="username" autocomplete="off" ng-model="user.username" ng-required="true"  ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="8" ng-pattern="/[0-9a-z]/i">
                <span class="error-message" ng-show="frmLogin.username.$dirty&& frmLogin.username.$error" ng-hide="frmLogin.username.$dirty&& frmLogin.username.$valid">
                    The Username is Mandatory
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="lineBox">
                <span class="label">Password</span>
                <input type="password"  autocomplete="off" name="psd" ng-model="user.password" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="8" ng-pattern="/[0-9a-z]/i">
                <span class="error-message" ng-show="frmLogin.psd.$dirty&&frmLogin.psd.$error" ng-hide="frmLogin.psd.$dirty&& frmLogin.psd.$valid">
                    The password is Mandatory
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="lineBox">
                <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" ng-disabled="frmLogin.$invalid" ng-click="submitLogin()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/admin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For the variable `postdata`, if you want to get the POST data of a form, use $_POST[param] instead.

Comment: The PHP you have shown - is that the entire contents from `php/checkLogin.php` ?

Comment: yes. the code is from related files

Comment: The first comment of bytec0de doesn't help because i send array and work with angular

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your PHP is structured - whether you have shown just a small extract from it or whether it is on the same page as the javascript. If the php is on the same page and you are posting (via ajax) to the same script then using `ob_clean()` will clear any output buffers created before it gets to your php

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        ob_clean();
        /* your php code - with PDO stuff */

        echo htmlspecialchars( $username, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );

        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <script>/* Your angularjs code */</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No my php is in separate page. There is an $http call. The problem is that i work with angular.js and angular.js send json instead of value. I'm new to PHP but as i understand i need a json decoder on php side in order to get values from that json. So, it works but when i add $pdo object i see all my html in echo instead of value. I want to work with absolutly separate code for server side and client side

Comment: Ok. Yes, in the php code you should decode the POSTed data using json_decode as your correctly state. I have never used `angularjs` but downloaded and tried to emulate your code but it doesn't work for me... probably missed some stuff! I can see no reason that the `$pdo` declaration would affect things - in the js, try debugging the `submitLogin` to see what it is sending over the POST ajax request. I did find that there was an error in the console when I just tried again - mentioneing `debugger`in the callback function. I removed that and the POST was sent though with empty params.ie:no data!

Comment: without $pdo it works. I see the echo result in my js file

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my issue was very easy: The returned html was the explanation of php error in connection statment.